# web services communication with .net and java

Tags: java, .net, web-services

can i replace this code in C#.net to java

```
[WebMethod]
    public int SendSMS( string Message, ref string MessageReturn) {
        string _res = string.Empty;
        _res = "defalt message";
        MessageReturn = _res; 
        return 0;
   }
```

i dont know ref string type in java

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy, because we can't pass a reference to a String and the value at that location in a method.

Workaround: wrap the String in a String array

```
public int SendSMS(String message, String[] messageReturn) {
    if (messageReturn == null || messageReturn.length != 1) {
        throw new AssertionError("Need to pass a length-1-String array");

    String res = "";
    res = "defalt message";
    messageReturn[0] = res; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is webservice, client is writen by .net and it used ref variable. So i have write a webservice to communicate with the .net client. And the problem is i dont know ref string in java.